# Delete lines between two patterns (with multiple occurrences) around a third pattern (single occurrence)

Tags: bash, pdf, sed, awk

I'm trying to edit an uncompressed PDF on macOS Monterey, and I want to delete objects that contain a certain pattern in their description. Such objects start with "X 0 obj" (where X is the object number) and end with "endobj". In the following simplified example, I would like to delete only the object that contains the string "ba r" (object 4, so lines 5 to 9).

```
line 1
3 0 obj
fo o
endobj
4 0 obj
quz
ba r
quz
endobj
5 0 obj
ba z
endobj
line 11
```

I've managed to use the following sed command to delete lines 7-9 with the following code, but nothing else…
`sed /'ba r'/,/endobj/d file.txt`

I think it could be done by reading the file in reverse (`tac file.txt`) and piping out to `sed`. Then deleting lines between "ba r" and "0 obj" excluding "ba r" itself. Then reverting the file reading order again and deleting lines between "ba r" and "endobj". Then saving the file with the same name.

However all my attempts with sed are failing, possibly due to single and double quotes (necessary for the spaces in "ba r"). Could anyone help? Or suggest a better approach? I'm open to try it `awk` if that makes it easier, but I'd prefer to use `sed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to write it in `sed`, exactly as described in the question:

```
tac file.txt | sed '/^ba r$/,/^[1-9] 0 obj$/{/^ba r$/p;d;}' | tac | sed '/^ba r$/,/^endobj$/d'
```

Answer (score 0):

The quotes for `sed` have to put like this, around *expression*:

```
sed '/ba r/,/endobj/d'
```

(not working as you expect).

If you have `sed` & `awk`, you have `perl`:

```
$ perl -0pe 's/^(ba r).*?endobj/$1/ms' file
line 1
3 0 obj
fo o
endobj
4 0 obj
quz
ba r
5 0 obj
ba z
endobj
line 11
```

Add `-i` switch if you want to edit *in place*:

```
perl -i -pe .......
```

Comment: Does this solves your answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your comment on how to quote `sed` around expression was actually super helpful and allowed me to be answer the question!

Unfortunately the question was about `sed` or `awk`, not `perl`; and the `perl`  command threw a compilation error to me so I cannot mark it as the accepted answer (I do not know enough about `perl` - so it might be me not knowing how to execute it).